# Создание компонента для Joomla

Tags: joomla

Как быстрее всего создать компонент для Joomla?) Может, если специальный софт для этого нормальный

Comment: софт под названием МОЗГ)

Comment: Красавец))

Answer (score 1):

Для меня полезным оказалась книга, где пошагово рзабирается создание компонента с нуля. Один написал по книге, второй сам, из третьего и четвертого вышли два сайта - коммерческие работы. Книгу не буду приводить - она под устаревшую уже Joomla 1.5, и к тому же, на англ.

Софта нет.

Answer (score 1):

[подробное руководство](http://joomlablog.ru/dokumentatsiya/dlya-razrabotchika/sozdanie-komponenta-dlya-joomla-2-5) вообще очень полезный блог, с кучей полезных советов

Answer (score 0):

Для создания компонентов я использую phpstorm. Там есть возможность быстрого создания компонента для joomla. 
Также есть множество платных и бесплатных онлайн сервисов для быстрого создания компонентов joomla.
Ищите по запрросу 'генератор компонентов joomla'

Comment: phpstorm это IDE  - среда разработки для языка PHP